# ipsec (openswan) routing or dns issue with iphone

Tags: nat, ipsec, iphone, point-to-point-protocol, xl2tpd

I got an established VPN connection, but either the routing or the resolving is not working.
The configuration is taken from http://louwrentius.com/blog/2011/12/setting-up-a-vpn-with-your-iphone-using-l2tp,-ipsec-and-linux/ and http://blog.bertelsen.co/2012/02/debian-squeeze-l2tpipsec-vpn-server.html

on the vpn server, doing an ngrep gives the following,
whereas 85.25.128.10 is the dns server:

```
interface: ppp0 (10.0.1.200/255.255.255.255)
#
U 10.0.1.201:55631 -> 85.25.128.10:53
  .............login.skype.com.....
#
U 10.0.1.201:55631 -> 85.25.128.10:53
  .............login.skype.com.....
#
U 10.0.1.201:55631 -> 85.25.128.10:53
  .............login.skype.com.....
#
U 10.0.1.201:55631 -> 85.25.128.10:53
  .............login.skype.com.....
#
```

what happens with the dns packets?
i cannot load any sites on the iphone client side.

edit: this works until the redirect:

```
####
T 10.0.1.201:51936 -> 10.0.1.200:80 [AP]
  GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: 10.0.1.200..Connection: keep-alive..Accept-Encoding: gzip,     deflate..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) Apple
  WebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25..Accept-    Language: de-de..Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*
  /*;q=0.8....
##
T 10.0.1.200:80 -> 10.0.1.201:51936 [AP]
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found..Date: Sat, 01 Jun 2013 13:40:38 GMT..Server: Apache/2..X-Powered-    By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15..Location: http://xxxxxxx.com/..Vary: Accept-Enco
  ding..Content-Encoding: gzip..Content-Length: 20..Keep-Alive: timeout=15,     max=100..Connection: Keep-Alive..Content-Type: text/html........................
##
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```